# Unity Problem with input selected in Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try this in unity

```
public class InputsNextFocusBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField _input1;
    public InputField _input2;
    public InputField _input3;
    public InputField _input4;
    public InputField _input5;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        _input1.onValueChanged.AddListener(arg0 =>
        {
            if (arg0.Length > 0)
            {
                _input2.Select();
            }
        });

        _input2.onValueChanged.AddListener(arg0 =>
        {
            if (arg0.Length > 0)
            {
                _input3.Select();
            }
        });

        _input3.onValueChanged.AddListener(arg0 =>
        {
            if (arg0.Length > 0)
            {
                _input4.Select();
            }
        });

        _input4.onValueChanged.AddListener(arg0 =>
        {
            if (arg0.Length > 0)
            {
                _input5.Select();
            }
        });

        _input5.onValueChanged.AddListener(arg0 =>
        {
            if (arg0.Length > 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("you are the best: the text input is" +
                          _input1.text + _input2.text + _input3.text + _input4.text + _input5.text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

basically when write a letter in the first inputField, select the next one, writes in the other an select next, until the last one.
In windows works ok, but in android around 3rd input, the touchscreenkeyboard does not appear anymore.
is there any way to solve this issue? or is there another alternative that works on windows and android? thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

This question has been bothering me for a long time.

Please do not switch the InputField component,use only one InputField component,change the inputfield.textcomponent.

But I also have confusion,some phone models pop up with minimal input.